# Can u please tell me whats the error mentioned here? I cant solve it further. Keil uvision5 IDE

Tags: keil, c51

test.c(8): error C141: syntax error near '(', expected ''

test.c(8): error C141: syntax error near 'unsigned', expected 'hdata'

test.c(8): error C141: syntax error near 'unsigned', expected 'hdata'

lines 8 ,49 and 56

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnVyZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en3RD.png)

Comment: Your compiler considers `data` to be a reserved keyword - notice how it colored differently by the editor's syntax highlighting?  You cannot use that as the name of a function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.